# Eigen/c++ multidimensionnel container

Tags: eigen

I'm looking for the best way to create container for different Eigen matrices. Something like :

```
Global(1,:,:) = mat_A;
Global(2,:,:) = mat_B;
```

Comment: Is `std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd>` sufficient? (Assuming by *different* you also mean different sizes, I don't see any other obvious solution)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks chtz, you helped me again :) , this combinaison between `Eigen` and `std::vector` is very powerfull, it can be used as container for multidimensionnal matrix, but one should set the size of the vector.

```
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

 MatrixXd A(3,3), B(3,3);

  A << 1, 2, 3,
       4, 1, 0,
       6, 9, 0; 

  B << 5, 8, 11,
       19, 0, 5,
       8, 0, 1;


  std::vector<MatrixXd> test(2);
  test[0]=A;
  test[1]=B;

  cout << test[0] << endl;
```